# Click event for multiple buttons in fragment not working

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-button

After trying to get all 3 of my buttons to use the same click event in a fragment, `public class FragmentShapesDemo extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements View.OnClickListener` becomes underlined red & returns an error:

> Class 'FragmentShapesDemo' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onClick(View)' in OnClickListener

I don't understand why this error is appearing when a click event has been implemented :-/

**fragment_shapes_demo.xml**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_1"
    android:onClick="btn_Click"
    android:text="@string/circles"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_2"
    android:onClick="btn_Click"
    android:text="@string/squares"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_3"
    android:onClick="btn_Click"
    android:text="@string/triangles"/>
```

**FragmentShapesDemo.java**

```
public class FragmentShapesDemo extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    Button button0;
    Button button1;
    Button button2;

    public FragmentShapesDemo() {
        // Required empty constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shapes_demo, container, false);

        button0 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
        button1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_2);
        button2 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_3);

        button0.setOnClickListener(this);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);

        return v;
    }

    public void btn_Click(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you using getActivity().findViewById() while you are inflating different View i.e v in your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete `onClick` from XML:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_1"

    android:text="@string/circles"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_2"
    android:text="@string/squares"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_3"
    android:text="@string/triangles"/>
```

Use your rootView reference to find the elements views. Also you can achieve button `onClick` with below code too:

```
public class FragmentShapesDemo extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    Button button0;
    Button button1;
    Button button2;

    public FragmentShapesDemo() {
        // Required empty constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shapes_demo, container, false);

        button0 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
        button1 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btn_2);
        button2 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btn_3);

        button0.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity, "Do Your Work", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });

        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });

        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to use the same click event for all of my buttons hence this answer is not efficient. How can I do this without having to type the code 3 times?

Comment: there are some structure of the code that we need to follow , as you want to achive it from for all buttons how can you define which button is clicked, you can choose first answer too . But as far i know there is no possiblity to acuiqure this power without proper id initialization.

Comment: Is it possible to merge all 3 click events into one? E.g. `button0|button1|button2.setOnClickListener `

Comment: No, Because android architecture identifies each of views with their unique id and perform action on those views. otherwise Checkout butter knife documentation, it may help  - https://dzone.com/articles/butter-knife-view-injection